# What are some guideline specifications for running a full Ethereum node using Geth 1.8?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, network, hardware

I'm keen to run a full Ethereum node to support the network. What are the guideline hardware requirements for this?

Comment: are you going to mine for profit, or just support the network by having a node in it and providing blockchain downloading "service"?

Comment: To support the network and also to learn more about Ethereum. Mining isn't on the cards.